# Black screen while trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu.

When I pressed install Ubuntu it goes into black screen

[image: 1st]

[image: 2st]

Comment: Did you select the `Try Ubuntu without installing` first?

Answer (score 0):

When the black screen starts you can wait for at least 2 minutes to check if it is stuck or something like that.
For the moment, run `Try Ubuntu without installing`. Like [Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) commented. Wait a while and see what happens. Ubuntu should be running and you should be able to watch desktop, use and so, install.